# Cannot figure out Why I am getting System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadExceptiom on a windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to install a test service on one of my development servers. I run the installation procedure given by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-install-and-uninstall-services). I went through the tutorial and got into trouble when I tried to install the service.

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version 4.6.1586.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Running a transacted installation.

Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.InstallLog.
Installing assembly 'C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   logfile = C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.InstallLog
   assemblypath = C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe
An exception occurred while trying to find the installers in the C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe assembly.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Aborting installation for C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe.

An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get installer types in the C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe assembly.
The inner exception System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was thrown with the following error message: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..

The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.InstallLog.
Rolling back assembly 'C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   logfile = C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.InstallLog
   assemblypath = C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe
An exception occurred while trying to find the installers in the C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe assembly.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Aborting installation for C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe.
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller installer.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get installer types in the C:\Users\fpettigrosso\Desktop\Win-Pak card updater\CardUpdaterService\bin\Debug\CardUpdaterService.exe assembly.
The inner exception System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was thrown with the following error message: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation. This exception will be ignored and the rollback will continue. However, the machine might not fully revert to its initial state after the rollback is complete.

The Rollback phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.
The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed.
```

Through a little research I came to a conclusion That I had no clue what is going on... I tried everything from dumping ddls into the same folder to rebuilding the solution. What other things I can try to do to figure out this problem?

the process uses linq

Comment: The referenced link is fine but some things to check; have you installed the correct version of .NET on the target machine? Are you sure any dependencies don't need other versions of .NET installed? Are all your dependencies in the same folder as the exe?

Comment: As from what I can tell. I have the correct .NET and I believe that the program has no dependencies.

Comment: Well the error message in the call stack there says `Unable to load one or more of the requested types` which means you're missing a dependency somewhere

Comment: the program does start another process via system.diagnostics.Process. would that be considered a dependency?

Comment: No, something core to your application is missing like a dll or pre-installed and registered library

Comment: hmmm ok let me do some investigation

Comment: I found something interesting in my code.... I get this remark from visual studio  this pieces of code
private static extern bool SetServiceStatus(ref ServiceStatus serviceStatus, IntPtr handle);



method operator, or access "service1.setservicestatus, intptr)' is marked external and has no attributeson it. consider adding a dllimport attribute to specify the external implementation

Comment: it turned out to be just that